# Heading come in all the rows

Tags: php

Heading come in all the rows need in first row

Need help with where i am going wrong

thank you

below is the code

```
<?php 
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'aria2', 'osvOSUxlY6wYLZzC'); //The      Blank string is the password
 mysql_select_db('torres');
 $query = "SELECT * FROM reports"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
   echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop    through results
  echo "<table><tr><th>CSQ_Name</th>
  <th>CSQ_ID</th>.......
$row..............  
   //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
             }
          echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML
   mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
```

Comment: i am not understand for your asking question describe more.

Comment: Echo your table header before the loop, not in the loop - Simple!

Comment: Never post usernames and password in your code here.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly, it's almost unreadable. and check that you close the quotes, remove unused lines of code before posting here, so people only focus on what is important.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to move the header portion out of the loop:

```
echo '<table><tr><th>CSQ_Name</th><th>CSQ_ID</th></tr>';   // start a table tag in the HTML
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {    //Creates a loop to loop   
  echo '<tr>';
  // output data here
  echo '<td>...</td><td>...</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML
```